# Стоит ли мне переходить с Python и Ruby на С#, в моем случае

Tags: python, веб-программирование, c#, .net, ruby

Возможно конечно вопрос покажется глупым) Дело в том, что я убежденный пользователь Windows. C этой системой я уже 9 лет. И телефон у меня на Windows Phone. Для меня это самая удобная система, так уж получилось.

Увлекаясь веб-разработкой, ранее для себя я выбрал питон и руби. Очень уж их все хвалят, вот и я решил попробовать. В целом мне нравится разработка на этих языках. Но сейчас я подумываю постепенно сместиться с веб-направления на мобильную разработку, и начать разрабатывать именно под мобильные Windows-системы. Язык C# мне нравится не меньше, чем вышеперечисленные языки. Если стану разрабатывать на .NET, то буду использовать одну технологию для обоих направлений (веб и mobile), что в принципе удобно. Для некоторых проектов на Питоне, а тем более на Руби, периодически приходится поднимать и настраивать виртуальные машины, что, скажу прямо, мне не очень удобно.

В общем, хочу освоить "универсальную" технологию, которая бы мне идеально подошла

P.S. Прошу не минусовать, никого не хотел обидеть и разжигать холивар тоже не планировал.  Спрашиваю исключительно для себя

Comment: Не знаю как вам, но лично меня откровенно тошнит от "иновационной" windows 8.

Comment: @Олег Серебряков, мне кажется, в Вашем случае обязательно надо переходить.

Comment: > Не знаю как вам, но лично меня откровенно тошнит от "иновационной" windows 8

открою вам страшную тайну - у Microsoft есть не только Win8. Windows 7 по-прежнему живее всех живых, и от нее даже никого особо не тошнит.

Comment: @DreamChild тем не менее есть куда более лучший линукс минт. Ну АВ пишет что у него винфон. Вот это - тройное соболезнование.

Comment: @Олег Серебряков попробуйте android на каком нибудь samsung galaxy s4 и сразу перемените своё мнение

Comment: @danpetruk и чем ваш куда лучший Mint лучше? Для обычного пользователя,  разумеется.

>более лучший
это вы у Светы из Иваново научились?

Comment: @DreamChild можно не париться, и пользоваться им как обычный юзверь, а можно открыть консоль и попасть в мир удивительных возможностей linux -а

Comment: ну и на кой черт весь этот "удивительный мир" нужен простому юзверю? Чего такого удивительного (и главное, позарез нужного) нет в Win но есть в Linux?

Comment: @DreamChild ну репозитории например

Comment: @danpetruk в доступе к репозиториям в Windows-системах пока проблем не заметил. Использую семерку. Гитхаб например предоставляет очень удобный клиент, пользуюсь в основном только им

Comment: @Олег Серебряков, посмотрите в сторону TFS.

Comment: @DreamChild не скажу за "обычного пользователя" (кстати, кто это? Можете назвать Ф.И.О?). Но под виндами проблемы установки халявного многоплатформенного софта могут возникать на ровном месте. А виндовый -- требует денежек.

Comment: @DreamChild, вы правы, пока, слава богам, windows 7 живее живых, проблема в том, что это временное явление, именно это я имел введу, прошу прощения за неочевидную дальновидность

Comment: Не надо переходить, надо выучить, и иметь обе технологии в руках.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Очень серьезное преимущество C# (а  вместе с ним и  .NET) кроется в том, что Microsoft выстроила вокруг всего этого очень ветвистую и большую экосистему, в которой можно вполне неплохо суествовать, будучи специалистом только лишь в технологиях, развиваемых Microsoft. Тот же самый C#, как правильно было замечено выше, позволяет писать и под десктоп (а Windows, на минуточку,  - это 90% рынка), и для web, и для мобильных платформ (хоть тут, конечно, все туманно и зыбко - уверенности в светлом будущем Windows Phone и иже с ним нету) 
Собственно, под экостистемой я пдразумевал не только языки, фреймворки, SDK, огромные библиотеки классов на все случаи жизни, СУБД и среду разработки, но еще и всеобъемлющие системы документации, MSDN, всяческие видеопорталы вроде TechDays. Все это довольно давно создано, местами даже активно развивается и предоставляет широкий простор для развития, так что аргументы в пользу C#, думаю, вполне весомы. Чем может похвастаться Ruby/Python я, пожалуй, сказать не смогу - но на этот вопрос вы, полагаю, сможете ответить себе сами

Comment: по поводу Python, как я отмечал выше, сказать ничего не могу, но если у ТСа есть какие-то причины хотеть с них уйти, то, вероятно, они для него значимы. А что касается правительства - вы сами-то в  эту их чепуху верите? Тем более, что на госучреждениях России свет клином не сошелся

Comment: Забыл упомянуть, что MS -платформенные расисты и POSIX операционки их злейший враг. Но, что характерно, почему-то именно POSIX занимают превалирующее положение на рынке - яблоки, андроиды, бада.

Comment: это если говорить о мобильных платформах. На десктопе адекватной конкуренции для Win нет

Comment: Это я к фразе `и начать разрабатывать именно под мобильные Windows-системы`. Стоило упомянуть это в противовес.

Comment: @DreamChild ну не верите Медведеву -- цитата из акулы капитализма:

      Thanks to OS X, Apple has come back from the dead in a way that is extremely rare in technology. Their victory is so complete that I'm now surprised when I come across a computer running Windows. Nearly all the people we fund at Y Combinator use Apple laptops. It was the same in the audience at startup school. All the computer people use Macs or Linux now. Windows is for grandmas, like Macs used to be in the 90s. So not only does the desktop no longer matter, no one who cares about computers uses Microsoft's anyway.

Comment: @alexlz: правительство-то заявило, а вы думаете, что хотя бы 0,1% госпредприятий ведёт документооборот не в MS Office? Вы думаете, что секретарша сможет поднять сетевой принтер под Ubuntu? Вы знаете много почтовых клиентов, совместимых с Аутлуком, чёрт бы его побрал? Не, Windows — это навсегда.

---
А «people at Y Combinator» — это гики, вы о чём. Они не будут у нас большинством ближайшие X лет.

Comment: @alexlz а с какого, простите, хрена я должен верить Медведеву? По его словам мы и восе живем едва ли не в самой лучшей стране, а наше Сколково-осколково уже вот-вот начнет выпускать Огромных Человекоподобных Боевых Роботов и всякую прочую нанотехнологичную продукцию. И потом, смотрите ответ от @VladD

P.S. Скажите пожалуйста, каким таким хитрым образом вы добавляете комментарии к собственно вопросу - я не могу этого делать уже после того, как их стало штук 15, а мне еще есть что сказать в той теме г-ну @danpetruk

Comment: @alexlz, отвечу вам тут

>не скажу за "обычного пользователя" (кстати, кто это? Можете назвать Ф.И.О?).

вы придираетесь к словам. Обычный пользователь - это любой рядовой пользователь компьютера, не разбирающийся в принципах его работы, не относящийся к IT-профессиям и работающий на уровне создания документов в Word. Таких - сотни миллионов. И именно они приносят миллиарды денег в карман Microsoft. Так вот что такого замечательного для этих людей может быть в Linux? Я вам отвечу - ничего. Иначе они давным-давно бы сидели под какой-нибудь Убунтой, тем более что она бесплатна.

Comment: @DreamChild: Я не закрываю и не обновляю вкладку с вопросом, тогда остаются возможность комментировать. Для чтения других комментариев использую соседнюю вкладку.

Comment: @DreamChild Несколько лет по ЕвроНьюс видел репортаж о внедрении линукс в госорганициях и интернет-центрах в Эстермадуре (автономия в Испании). Эффект нехилый.

А насчёт ворда -- так им мало кто умеет пользоваться. Шесть лет назад был случай (не помню, описывал здесь или нет). Парень делал устройства на микроконтроллерах, документацию к ним в ворде (вроде как по ЕСКД). Но дело Поносова, проверки потенциальных пиратов, ОпенОфис и съехавшие шаблоны документов. И до отпуска чуть-чуть. Поставили ему cygwin, latex, пакет eskdx -- как он был доволен... Даже разреши ему ворд - возвращаться бы не ста

Comment: @VladD а нафига совместимость клиентов в аутлуком? Exchange forever? И нафига секретарше "поднимать сетевой принтер"? Не её это дело. (Хотя, по Каганову

     Девочки пришли рыдать,
     Типа неполадка.
     Ну настроил им печать,
     Трахнув для порядка.)

А всяких OpenOffice'ов в 2007г. развелось немало, когда начались антипиратские проверки. Линух однозначно проигрывает в играх.

Хотя все эти ворды/райтеры на рабочем месте -- инструмент офисного планктона. Имитация вместо работы.

Вейцман приводил пример, что знал (в начале нулевых) две фирмы в США, отказавшиеся от вордов.

Comment: @alexlz: Не, я не про Еxchange, я про tnef (OLE-формат вложений), который Аутлук использует, и который нормально не читается другими почтовыми клиентами. Насчёт секретарши — замените её на любого условного «новичка». [ESR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond), например, в своё время [не смог](http://www.catb.org/~esr/writings/cups-horror.html).

Comment: @alexlz:  Насчёт OpenOffice: он до сих пор объективно слабее, не имеет «защиты от дурака», плохо совместим с Microsoft'овскими форматами (любой документ с таблицами, созданный Word'ом, «разъезжается» в OO Writer'е), и непривлекателен с т. зр. дизайна (сорри, секретаршам это тоже важно). Поскольку «офисный планктон» составляет большинство работников в стране по факту, именно они будут задавать тон, и орать благим матом при попытке пересадить их на FOSS. Вот антипиратские проверки, это да, это в принципе может повлиять. Но я бы не ставил на это.

Comment: > no one who cares about computers uses Microsoft's anyway(2007)

аминь

Answer (score 8):

Ну, начнем с того, что C# все таки не технология. А по сабжу - зная .NET сейчас можно охватить много разных областей - и десктопные приложения, и мобильные, и веб (мне вот например Razor очень понравился). Ну и Visual Studio 2012 хороша, хотя это оффтоп :) Мелкомягкие сейчас активно пиарят XAML, привыкнуть не всегда просто, но когда привыкнешь UI делать неплохо.

Имхо - попробовать стоит.

**UPD:** ну и кстати, не забывайте про SDK типа Mono, которые позволяют писать приложения под яблоки-андроиды используя дотнет.

Comment: да, я скорее имел ввиду дотнет, а не чистый C# )

Answer (score 5):

Настраивать виртуальные машины придется и с разработкой с использованием .net, это явно не должно быть причиной смены используемых технологий.

ИМХО, сама по себе разработка вряд ли будет чем-то кардинально отличаться. Те же костыли, те же грабли.

P.S.
+1 к Razor, который упомянул [@Макс Жуков](/users/6941/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81-%D0%B6%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Comment: Да, но зато фактически будет одна технология для мобильной и веб-разработки. Подучу C#, а там и до Java недалеко)

Answer (score 5):

По-моему мнению, нужно отталкиваться не от нужно/ненужно, а от денег :) если вы можете себе обеспечить такой же заработок на python/ruby, то C# можно учить чисто ради общего развития. В Киеве .Net программист получает больше Python программиста.

Еще мое мнение. Если вы фрилансер, то .Net вам в работе не понадобиться. Скажите заказчику, что вам нужен вот такой веб сервер с Windows на борту(платим за лицензию) + MSSQLServer(с лицензией по количеству ядер), и он найдет человека, который напишет ему сайт на php/python/ruby. .Net - в большинстве своем удел больших энтерпрайзов(и соответственно аутсорсеров).

Следуйте тому, что вам нравится. Но не забывайте, что нужно кормить себя и свою семью. В любом случаи - знание дополнительного языка НИКОГДА не было минусом. Ни на собеседовании, ни во фрилансе(потому что знаете, как круто сделано в одной платформе, а может есть нечто подобное и в другой платформе. Другими словами, у вас есть кругозор).

И то же с Windows - вам нравится, развивайтесь. Но не забывайте смотреть по сторонам и спрашивать, почему в других ОС было сделано иначе.

Вывод: смотрите по бюджету в вашем регионе и ваших желаниях. Смотрите по сторонам. Учите новые языки программирования(но минимум в одном вы должны быть профи)

Comment: Спасибо) Насчет серверов - есть Windows Azure с весьма недорогим хостингом, если не ошибаюсь

Comment: @Олег Серебряков, на Azure международное коммьюнити раньше сильно недоговало. Сейчас - не знаю, мб лучше стало...
@Антон Феоктистов, а вот вопрос рентабельности, вы правы, один из важнейших.

Comment: @Олег Серебряков 
кстати, да. Недавчно читал про то, как проект на Django деплоили в Azure) Но сервису только три года, а .Net больше 10 лет. Дело в том, что я из смежного мира Java, но там все примерно так же на счет enterprise. Тем не менее, пару месяцев назад я познакомился с python+Django, и не представляю как писал бы на столько простые вещи на Java. Для своих целей Django - шикарно. Но смотря на зарплатные ожидания понимаю, что python пока только хобби)

Очень мало банков переходят с .Net/Java на что-то другое. Тем более там выбор технологий чаще решается за игрой в гольф, увы.

Comment: @Макс Жуков
http://habrahabr.ru/post/163855/ - а вот и та статья :)

Comment: @Антон Феоктистов, угу, интересно. но я имел ввиду саму облачную технологию Azure, не нравилась она народу :) я никогда не работал с облаками, но под "давлением общественного мнения" пошел бы по пути OpenStack. хотя я допускаю что чего-то не понимаю.

Answer (score 4):

> Но сейчас я подумываю постепенно
> сместиться с веб-направления на
> мобильную разработку, и начать
> разрабатывать именно под мобильные
> Windows-системы.

В такой формулировке только C# и без вариантов.

Но если формулировка была бы:

> Но сейчас я подумываю постепенно
> сместиться с веб-направления на
> мобильную разработку

Тогда только Java или Objective C и без вариантов - увы. Поскольку доля Win систем под мобильниками не более 2-3% и вы быстро останетесь без хлеба владея только Win разработкой для мобильников.

В общем вы решите, что для вас важнее - мобильная разработка "as-is" или унылый с*кс с любимым Windows :) - без обид.

Я тоже люблю Windows, но жизнь с Java/Android/iOS как то поприятнее будет...

Comment: Отцензурировал :)

Comment: @Barmaley Вообще-то доля Windows Phone больше, и она пока что растет. Я думаю, освоив C#, на Java перейти не проблема - это как с Python перейти на Ruby (я уже пробовал делать такой переход, ничего сложного не возникло) Могу ошибаться

Comment: На сколько я знаю, приложения на C# можно без проблем портировать на другие платформы, если говорить о мобильной разработке

Comment: @Олег Серебряков - это миф

Comment: @Олег Серебряков рекомендую снять розовые очки и посмотреть в лицо суровой реальности. Доля WP да растет: аж выросла с 2% до 3% - это несомненно успех :) - [пруфлинк](http://venturebeat.com/2013/05/16/windows-phone-jumps-to-third-in-global-smartphone-market-share-and-could-be-second-faster-than-you-think/)

Comment: @Barmaley Еще один пруф: http://itnews.com.ua/analitics/386.html Помимо той таблицы, из этой статьи можно узнать, что доля WP в России (я пока ориентируюсь на российский рынок) приближается к 10%. Не все так печально)

Comment: @Олег Серебряков Вы задали вопрос - я ответил, как человек занимающийся мобильной разработкой около 10 лет. Выводы делайте сами. Отделяйте зерна от плевел - рекламная статья проплаченная Microsoft/Nokia или голая статистика от независимого исследователя - это разные вещи. Я писал под WP, остался весьма недоволен - хотя бы вопрос backward совместимости WP7 и WP8 - одно это способно "убить" любого разработчика.

Comment: @Barmaley Раз так, то респект Вам и уважуха, я только начинаю интересоваться мобильной разработкой!) Насчет Java еще раз подумаю

Comment: @Олег Серебряков тут дело не так в java, как в том, что-бы заниматся не только тем, что нравится, но и тем, чем заниматся целесообразно :)

Answer (score 3):

По-моему, задавая данный вопрос, вы сами в нем же ответили. Отталкиваясь от высказываний:

> В общем, хочу освоить "универсальную" технологию, которая бы мне идеально подошла
>
> Если стану разрабатывать на .NET, то буду использовать одну технологию для обоих направлений (веб и mobile), что в принципе удобно
>
> Язык C# мне нравится не меньше, чем вышеперечисленные языки

**Переходите на C#**

Comment: логично, но пока я замер в нерешительности)

Answer (score 1):

Для каждой задачи - свой инструмент. Для веб-приложений ничего лучше Ruby и Python вы не найдёте (если только умеете правильно ими пользоваться). Для WP - выбирайте сами. Переходить никуда не нужно, используйте в каждом случае более подходящий инструмент. Увы, из универсального, даже в плане исключительно мобильной разработки - ничего нет, кроме как PhoneGap, но и тот не без недостатков.

Comment: @pirj

     Для веб-приложений ничего лучше Ruby и Python вы не найдёте (если только умеете правильно ими пользоваться)

А если найдёте -- значит не умеете...

Comment: В том то и дело, что хочу найти универсальный инструмент, который одинаково хорошо подошел бы и для веб, и для мобильной разработки, а возможно еще и для десктопной. И при этом я готов ограничиться экосистемой Windows. Ну не лежит у меня душа к Linux, хоть тресни. Против Python ничего не имею, но немного напрягает дилемма с ветками (2-я или 3-я) и огромное количество библиотек и модулей, которое нужно учитывать. А Ruby не очень-то Windows-friendly язык

Comment: @Олег Серебряков, основная Ваша проблема тут в том, что большинство новых разработок делается людьми у которых не лежит душа к Windows, хоть тресни.

Часть из этих разработок (часто кривенько) кто-то переносит на винду, 
 но в целом процесс идет в перпендикулярном к Вашим устремлениям направлении.

Безусловно, винда устраивает огромное количество "обычных" пользователей. Правда большинству из них ничего особо нового и не нужно.

Comment: @pirj, можно сказать "если умеете пользоваться" и назвать метлу самолетом.

Comment: А как же java ee? Тоже оч. хороша для web-development

Comment: @danpetruk, я фрилансер, для меня Java не очень-то подходит, разве что если переберусь на разработку под Android

Comment: @Олег Серебряков да я про фразу АО говорил:
> Для веб-приложений ничего лучше Ruby и Python вы не найдёте